# The meaning of “caterpillar” as a verb

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

From "Dunkirk: Fight to the Last Man" by Hugh Sebag-Montefiore, quoting RWS's Captain Walter Clough-Taylor:

"... I noticed there were girders, rising to about a foot in height in the centre [of the bridge], above the roadway. I flung myself down, and **caterpillaring** madly along behind one of them arrived miraculously on the other side."

What does "caterpillar" mean here? Is it to crawl like a caterpillar?

Comment: Hello, Michael. You should include evidence of research on ELU, even if it's negative (eg 'Lexico, Collins and AHD don't give a verb usage' [I haven't actually checked]). But I can't see what else it could mean. 'Snake' and 'worm' have been verbed.

Comment: I would consider it an unremarkable term meaning "crawl like a caterpillar".